# js regex discrepancy

Tags: javascript, regex, brackets

I have a JS regex match that seems to include the brackets incorrectly. I tested it out at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rJ4hV3/9) and it seems to work appropriately there but when I run it I get this alert response:

`[#],[Type,' '],[Problem w/ICD],['- ',Assessment],[' : ',Comment],[LF],[LF]`

```
var temp = "[#]. [Type,' '][Problem w/ICD]['- ',Assessment][' : ',Comment][LF][LF]";
var rep = temp.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g);
alert(rep);
```

Why are the brackets included when they are outside the capture group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brackets are included because when using [`string#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and a regex with `/g` modifier, you will lose capturing groups.

> If the regular expression includes the `g` flag, the method returns an Array containing all matched substrings rather than match objects. **Captured groups are not returned.**

You need to use a `RegExp#exec()` in a loop, and access the first capturing group via index 1.

```js
var re = /\[(.*?)\]/g; 
var str = '[#]. [Type,\' \'][Problem w/ICD][\'- \',Assessment][\' : \',Comment][LF][LF]';
var m;
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Result:

```
["#", "Type,' '", "Problem w/ICD", "'- ',Assessment", "' : ',Comment", "LF", "LF"]
```

Comment: Just FYI: [`/\[([^[\]]*)\]/g`](https://regex101.com/r/hB9qQ9/1) is more effecient in this case.